# Поиск и запись строк

Tags: python

Я в Python новичек, столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Необходимо найти строку в файле; если она отсутствует, то необходимо выполнить часть кода и записать строку, которую мы искали в файл, а если эта строка есть в файле, то ничего не выполнять.

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. Что именно вам не понятно? Как читать из файла? Как в прочитанном найти строку? Как выполнить часть кода по условию? Как записать строку в файл? Задайте конкретный вопрос и вам помогут. Но писать за вас программу целиком никто не будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val = """
строка1
строка2
строка3
строка4
"""

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(val)

def search(test):
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if test in line:
                print("В файле есть строка `{}`".format(test))
                test = ""
                break
        if test:
            f.close()
            with open('test.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.writelines(test+"\n")
                print("В файл дописали строку `{}`".format(test))


search("строка7")
В файл дописали строку `строка7`

search("строка7")
В файле есть строка `строка7`
```

Comment: возможно ли вставить код в комментарий?

Comment: @ex3m777  вставить код можно, но я не пойму о каком `комментарии` вы говорите.